# Fixed view through various activities in Android

Tags: android, admob, android-activity

How do you implement a fixed view through various activities in Android 2.1 upwards? By *fixed* I mean that the view should retain its state when the activity changes.

In particular, I'd like to have an [Admob AdView](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals) on top of every activity without reloading the ad every time the app starts a new activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible using different activities. But you could use only one activity and split your screens through multiple fragments inside this activity and adding/removing them while keeping your fixed view untouched.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The `Activity` is the basis of the app's user interface, and every `View` must live within the `Activity`'s parent `ViewGroup`. Since every `Activity` must be created when it is initially launched, every `View` that lives inside the `Activity` must be inflated and attached to the `Activity`s layout.

What you could do instead is pass the information required to instantiate the specific admob `View` to the next `Activity` with an `Intent`.

Comment: TabActivity does something similar, so it must be possible.

Comment: However, the way TabActivity does it is deprecated.

Comment: So did it end up being possible w/ multiple activities? I still can't think of a way...